# Convert json to proper geojson with geojson.min.js

Tags: json, leaflet, geojson, data-conversion

So i have json data with column geo_coordinates, i use leaflet library to display geojson, unfortunately leaflet cannot read geo_coordinates because it doesnt know that is type Point and coordinates for it.

I was looking after best solution and i though that i should change geo_coordinates on "type": Point  "coordinates" :

I found geojson.min.js, it looks simple to use, but i am doing sth wrong mayby sb can help.

```js
var map;


    // set up the map
 map = new L.Map('map');

 // create the tile layer with correct attribution
 var kanomapUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
 var kanomap = new L.TileLayer(kanomapUrl, {minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 18});

 
 map.setView(new L.LatLng(8.783268,11.95733),1);
 map.addLayer(kanomap);


$.getJSON("/api/facility/", function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data);
    GeoJSON.parse(geojson, {Point: ['geo_coordinates']});
   geojson.addTo(map);
  });
```

My json

```js
[{"id": 10, "name": "Berlin", "country": "Germany", "geo_coordinates": "1.153757,11.634342"}, ......]
```

gejJson is wroking i checked it with some data from google and it is displayed correctly, the same when i type some geojson manually, then everything works. So i am sure i do sth wrong with geojson library to convert my json properly

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are speaking of https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson ...

Your geo_coordinates field is too complex ... 
The library requires 2 distinct fields from your data structure to define a Point (one for latitude, one for longitude).

Why do you want to convert to geojson ? Can't you process the data yourself ?

Comment: actually you are right i just could process data myself, but i work with json format that sb give me, but thanks i know now what to do to make it work ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tweak a few things:

1) As @FranceImage mentioned you have to set up your coordinates in your source data 
differently, for example as an array:

```
{"id": 10, "name": "Berlin", "country": "Germany", "geo_coordinates": [1.153757, 11.634342]}
```

2) In Leaflet, it seems if you add raw GeoJson data, you have to use the addData function

```
var result = GeoJSON.parse(geojson, {Point: 'geo_coordinates'});   
var geojson = L.geoJson().addData(result);
```

See here for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n82d4s91/5/